# SQL DML Exercise 10

Tags: sql, dml

I've used SO often but never signed up. I have a problem I'm stuck on and I can't figure out how to get the correct query. So first off, this question is in reference to www.sql-ex.ru and  its Exercise 10 in the DML section.

Here is all the info:

> The database scheme consists of four tables: Product(maker, model,
>   type) PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price) Laptop(code, model,
>   speed, ram, hd, screen, price) Printer(code, model, color, type,
>   price) The table "Product" includes information about the maker, model
>   number, and type ('PC', 'Laptop', or 'Printer'). It is assumed that
>   model numbers in the Product table are unique for all the makers and
>   product types. Each PC uniquely specifying by a code in the table "PC"
>   is characterized by model (foreign key referencing to Product table),
>   speed (of the processor in MHz), total amount of RAM - ram (in Mb),
>   hard disk drive capacity - hd (in Gb), CD ROM speed - cd (for example,
>   '4x'), and the price. The table "Laptop" is similar to that one of PCs
>   except for the CD ROM speed, which is replaced by the screen size -
>   screen (in inches). For each printer in the table "Printer" it is told
>   whether the printer is color or not (color attribute is 'y' for color
>   printers; otherwise it is 'n'), printer type (laser, jet, or matrix),
>   and the price.
>
> Add into the PC table all the models from the Product table that are
>   absent from the PC table.
>
> Along with above the inserted models must have the specifications:
>
> 1. The code should be equal to the model number plus maximal code value which has been in the PC table before insert operation.
> 2. Speed, RAM and HD capacities, and CD-speed should be maximal among all available corresponding values in the PC table.
> 3. The price should be an average among all the PCs which have been in the PC table before insert operation.

Here is my Query:

```
INSERT INTO PC 
   SELECT 
      p.model + MAX(pc.code),
      p.model,
      MAX(pc.speed) speed, 
      MAX(pc.ram) ram, 
      MAX(pc.hd) hd, 
      MAX(pc.cd) cd,
      AVG(pc.price) price 
   FROM 
      product p, pc pc 
   WHERE 
      type= 'pc' 
   AND 
      p.model NOT IN (SELECT model from pc) 
   GROUP BY 
      p.model
```

Now Im getting the correct result but the following error:

> Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed
>   test on second, checking database.
>   * Data mismatch (1)

Which from their FAQ means:

> If the answer is logically right, it will always be regarded as right
>   answer. There is a small possibility that logically wrong answer will
>   be regarded as right. To figure out if the query is right two
>   databases with identical structure and different data are used. If
>   system tells you that your query is wrong but you can see matching
>   results, that means your query gives the wrong answer on the second
>   database. And still there is a possibility that logically incorrect
>   query will return right resulting set. That possibility can be
>   decreased by accurate data selecting or by using more than two
>   databases to check the query. Second way is less attractive because it
>   will take more time for response to users. Let us note, that once
>   formulated query should always return correct result regardless of
>   current database state. If you have reasoned doubts about the
>   correctness of judgment of the query, please send your code to the
>   developers of the system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I see you have a `FROM` clause with two tables `product, pc` but no condition joining them.  Preferably this would be something like `FROM product p INNER JOIN pc ON p.some_common_column = pc.some_common_column`  Or using your implicit method `WHERE p.some_common_column = pc.some_common_column`

Comment: Reading the description, looks like `model` is the common column, so `FROM product p INNER JOIN pc ON p.model = pc.model`

Comment: I tried that but now it eliminated the last two rows required to be correct.

Comment: Your original `p.model NOT IN (SELECT model from pc)` suggests that there are rows in `product` which do not have corresponding rows in `pc`. Instead of an `INNER JOIN`, does `LEFT JOIN`  should cover that use case.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I am a complete SQL newb so bear with me. I've never posted here so its throwing me off. Left Join gives me all the results but the last two aren't there and it seems they or some other results are null across the table for the first two results.

Comment: This is difficult to debug simply by envisioning how it should be. (In fact, I missed the purpose of the `p.model NOT IN (SELECT model from pc)` which effectively did join your tables in the first place, making my first comment a moot point).  Can you setup a sample of the two tables over at http://sqlfiddle.com with the row data you are currently working with? Also, edit above to include an example of what you expect the output data to be.

Comment: Also at http://sqlfiddle.com, you can test your setup in different RDBMS. Since your problem in the first place was that you got the expected result, but not when tested against another database type, you may be able to narrow down where it fails (MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, etc)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the cd speed is treated as string not as number.
So for example the 2x is more than 16x. You have to make cd speed a number.

But it has 'x' on its end, which you have to trim. Then you can cast it to
number and run max() function on it properly. In the end you have to cast
it back to string and re-add the 'x' to its end.

Here is the working code

> `INSERT INTO PC
>   SELECT 
>         p.model + MAX(pc.code) code,
>         p.model,
>         MAX(pc.speed) speed, 
>         MAX(pc.ram) ram,
>
>         MAX(pc.hd) hd,
>         CAST(MAX(CAST(REPLACE(pc.cd,'x','')AS int))AS varchar)+'x' cd, 
>         AVG(pc.price) price 
>   FROM 
>         product p
>   INNER JOIN  pc
>   ON
>         p.type= 'pc' 
>   WHERE
>         p.model NOT IN (SELECT model from pc) 
>   GROUP BY 
>         p.model`<

Actually thanks for your code :) 
I wasnt able to figure it out by myself.
Once I copied yours, then I found the issue quite quickly :)